# I can't remove Content Type programmatically? How I can do it? SharePoint Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, content-type, custom-list

I create in SPD 2010 workflow which create custom content type with column. I removed workflow, list and column and I also want to remove content typ but I can't do it, SharePoint shows this info "The content type is in use" How remove this content type?

I use SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Designer 2010.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

There can be any of many reasons in your case,

e.g.

This error happens when there is a dependency or another object in SharePoint that uses the content type:

- A list/library that is already using the content type.
- Items in the list/library that use the content type.

I would recommend you to look at these blogs

[error-content-type-still-in-use](http://njbblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/error-content-type-still-in-use.html)

[Content Type in use error](http://www.dotnetking.com/TechnicalComments.aspx?LogID=371)

Comment: You should post a summary or quote of those references. Basically the first link says there is a item or library that is still using the content type and you must locate this and delete or change the content type. This is 100% a manual process. The second link basically says items in the recycle bin count and to make sure and check there if you've already checked everywhere else.

Comment: @shufler  links are already there , I didn't put anything that isn't referenced "somehow" :)

Comment: yup, like in my answer I said there can be any of many reasons he is not able to delete content type so in above two links they are either telling how to delete it or error they faced, more like example to person so that he gets idea what can go wrong, as no one can say why he cant exactly delete content type as it could be anything related to his sharepoint environment :)

Comment: Dear All, I removed many files from my recycle bin and I was able to removed my old content type :) Can I check manualy which things uses content type? Thanks you for support, yours answers were very helpful for me :) Regards

Comment: Without getting too far into a discussion outside of the scope of this question, my comments are directed more to the spirit of this site. I'm not saying you didn't cite a source, I'm saying your answer will no longer be valid if the source site disappears one day and users can no longer click the links!

Comment: Hi Andrzej, are you saying you can now remove the content type after removing files from the recycle bin?

Comment: Sorry that I answer so late, Yes I removed contet type after removed all things from recycle bin... Why do You ask?